# Vim: Ignore Special Path in Search

Tags: search, vim, findinfiles

In my .vimrc file, I have two very useful lines:

```
set path=~/nbapp/**
set backupdir=~/nbapp/temp
```

The first line allows me to search in my project directory and subdirectories. The second line makes vim create backup files in a special temporary folder, rather than disturbing me by adding tens of backup files having the exact same name except for a '~' at the end. However, since the temporary files are still inside the 'nbapp' folder (and I want to keep them there because they are related to the project), it means they are also going to be searched when I make a search, which sometimes disturb me, because I keep looking at searched results, yet to discover that they are actually in the temporary folder.

Is there any possible way to exclude paths from search (i.e. vimgrep)? I want to exclude the 'temp' folder.

Regards,
Rafid

Answer (score 28):

Use the 'wildignore' option:

`:set wildignore+=**/temp/**`

or if you would like to be more specific:

`:set wildignore+=~/nbapp/temp/**`

This should exlude all files in the nbapp/temp directory in :find result.

Comment: I was looking for exactly this, for ignoring build folders in :find searches. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me in vim 7.4

Answer (score 6):

Instead of vimgrep I use the grep command

```
:help grep
```

I use the setting

```
set grepprg=grep\ -nIh\ --exclude=tags\ --exclude=cscope.out
```

when I want to search files but excluding the tag files and cscope files.
You could modify the above to not search any files ending with a ~.
I don't think you can exclude the folder using grep (or maybe you can, try --exclude=~/nbapp/temp/* it might work I haven't tested it).

If that does not work I recomend using ack for the grepprg instead of grep.
ack as an option ignore-dir=name in which you can explicitly ignore a folder.

Comment: Recent versions of grep has `--ignore-dir` too, which might be just what you are looking for.

Comment: To not break quickfix window better would be `set grepprg=grep\ -n\ --exclude=tags\ --exclude=cscope.out\ $*\ /dev/null`

Answer (score 5):

To exclude some dirs from `:find` and `gf` (for example `node_modules`)
you can set:

```
:set path=**
:set wildignore+=*/node_modules/*
```

Comment: Apparently you've never listened to [Jimmy Soul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qh9ZZgDqzAg)

Comment: @WayneWerner I didn't got your comment. Right after 2 years ago :)

Comment: I'm pretty confused at the moment exactly what in the world I meant at the time :D

Comment: `set wildignore` looks like do nothing when in `.vim/ftplugin`.

Answer (score 0):

For example in Ubuntu just

```
sudo apt-get install ack-grep

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ack-grep /usr/bin/ack
```

then install http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572

and now add next line to your .vimrc

```
noremap <C-f> :copen<CR>:Ack --ignore-dir #first_ignore_dir# --ignore-dir #second_ignore_dir# -ai
```

- its open search frame by Ctr+F, have fun

Answer (score -1):

```
set path-=~/nbapp/temp
```

is the preferred method of removing path entries, as it guards you against vim upgrades that may modify the value of 'path'.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working! It still shows me the backup files.